# Multiple condition if statement with regexmatch

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I wrote this code, but for the life of me I can't get it to validate correctly.

There is data on row[14] defined as var voicemailed. Some of these cells in this column on Google Sheets contain 'VM' in their string to show that a voicemail was left. The script is meant to then email the client once marked that a voicemail was left.

What did I do wrong here?

```
    // This constant is written in column S for rows for which an email
    // has been sent successfully.
    var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

    /**
     * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
     */
    function sendEmails2() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var startRow = 857; // First row of data to process
      var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
      // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
      var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3);
      // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
      var data = dataRange.getValues();
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[12]; // M column
        var message = row[17]; // R column
        var emailSent = row[18]; // S column
        var voicemailed = row[14]; // O Column, checks to see if 'vm' in cell
        if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT && voicemailed === voicemailed.REGEXMATCH(voicemailed,"VM")) { // Prevents sending duplicates and checks if row has VM entry
          var subject = row[16]; // Q column
          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
          sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
          // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Try to test with REGEXMATCH(voicemailed,".VM+")

Comment: I tried that, still errors as "not defined".

Comment: Please check this one voicemailed === voicemailed.REGEXMATCH(voicemailed,"VM"), here you compare something that I think they are different

Comment: May be you must change it to: emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT &&  voicemailed.REGEXMATCH(voicemailed,".VM+")

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm still getting the error that the regexmatch is undefined.

Comment: Try to use logger.log to check where your code give undefined and put Logger.log voicedmail; under ITS declaration

Comment: And try to change regexmatch with match

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this:

```
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT && RegExp("VM").test(voicemailed))
    {
      ..... 
    }
```

Please try again with this (voicemailed must be a string):

```
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT && voicemailed.match(/VM/i)=='VM') 
    {
      ..... 
    }
```

Comment: The answer given is finally halting the "undefined" error which is huge! Unfortunately it's still throwing an error about my regexp flag.  An example string is "VM 01/01/2019". I tried the answer above with the flag ".VM+" because I understand where other commenters were going with this, but that still threw a bad flag error.

Comment: I have modified the script